# Server validation in in a single choice question

Tags: limesurvey

It seems that when you send the answer to a single choice question (dropdown), Limesurvey now makes a server validation to check if the selected answer belongs to the options defined for that question at survey creation time.

The problem is that I want to add new options via javascript, so when one of the new ones is chosen and the form is sent, Limesurvey complains that it is not a valid answer.

Do you know how to circumvent this limitation?

Thanks

LS Versión 3.15.9+190214

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround - use a short-text question and build a complete drop-down to load it with JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you tpartner, that could be a fallback if there is no more options. Nevertheless, I hoped that I wasn't forced to put that overhead on every question, as it adds extra complexity.